# В SQLite при создании таблицы для телеграмм бота выдаёт выдаёт ошибку после нажатия в боте '/start'

Tags: python, sql

Когда я нажимаю на '/start' в боте, в терминале выдаёт такую ошибку

Ошибка:
**unrecognized token: ""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_in_chat(
id INTEGER       )"**

Код:

```
#database
connect = sqlite3.connect('pomagator')
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute(""""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALTER TABLE 'users_in_chat'(id INTEGER,
)""")         
connect.commit()

#proverka
people_id = message.chat.id
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users_in_chat WHERE id = {people_id}")

#все поля с айди 
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    #spisok polzovatilei
    user_id = [message.chat.id]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users_in_chat VALUES(?);", user_id)
    connect.commit()
```

Comment: Лишняя **"** в начале

Comment: И странный запрос в коде `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALTER TABLE 'users_in_chat'(id INTEGER,)` -- нужно делать что-то одно -- или `CREATE TABLE` или `ALTER TABLE`; к тому же лишняя запятая в конце списка полей таблицы.

Answer (score -1):

```py
connect = sqlite3.connect('pomagator')
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALTER TABLE 'users_in_chat'(id INTEGER)")         
connect.commit()
people_id = message.chat.id
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users_in_chat WHERE id = ?", people_id)

data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users_in_chat VALUES (?);", (message.chat.id,))
    connect.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, днем попробую, меня тоже смутил момент что в ошибке выдается разное количество "